Calculations not completing with dropdown values - Jquery
New to jquery and have a medication calculator. The values in the calculator can be user defined and this works as expected. However I am trying to have the fields populated by a drop-down (SQL query driven) as an alternative option.
The dropdown
        <select name="stock_item_used" name="stock_item_used" id="stock_item_used" required>
        <option value="" disabled selected>Medication</option>
        <?php
        //Find medications
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * from rescue_medication_trans
        LEFT JOIN rescue_medications ON rescue_medication_trans.med_profile_id = rescue_medications.medication_id
        LEFT JOIN rescue_stock_medication ON rescue_stock_medication.medication = rescue_medication_trans.med_profile_id
        WHERE rescue_medication_trans.centre_id = :centre_id
        ORDER BY common_name ASC");
        $stmt->bindParam(':centre_id', $centre_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);     
        // initialise an array for the results
        $instock = array();
        $stmt->execute();
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

        $med_profile_id = $row["med_profile_id"];
        $batch_number = $row["batch_number"];
        $expiry = $row["expiry"];
        $med_common_name = $row["common_name"];
        $mcd = $row["concentration_dose"];
        $mcv = $row["concentration_volume"];
        $dose_type = $row["concentration_dose_type"];
        $volume_type = $row["concentration_volume_type"];

        //format the exp date
        $exp = new DateTime($expiry);
        $exp = $exp->format('d-m-Y');
                                            
print '<option value="' . $med_profile_id . '" data-dose="' . $mcd . '" data-volume="' . $mcv . '">' . $med_common_name . ' - ' . $mcd . '<i>' . $dose_type . '</i>  in ' . $mcv . '<i>' . $volume_type. '</i> (' . $batch_number . ' exp: ' . $exp . ') </option>'; } ?> </select> 

The jquery script
    <script>
    
var req_dose = 0;
var med_dose = 0;
var med_vol = 0;
var weight = 0;

$("#required_dose").change( function(){
    req_dose = $("#required_dose").val();
    calcTotals();
});
$("#medication_dose").change( function() {
    med_dose = $("#medication_dose").val();
    calcTotals();
});
$("#medication_volume").change( function() {
    med_vol = $("#medication_volume").val();
    calcTotals();
});
$("#animal_weight").change( function() {
    weight = $("#animal_weight").val();
    calcByweight();
});

var selectdose = document.getElementById("stock_item_used");
selectdose.addEventListener("change", function() {
  var optiondose = selectdose.options[selectdose.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-dose");
  document.getElementById('medication_dose').value = optiondose;
  calcTotals();
  calcByweight();
});

var selectvol = document.getElementById("stock_item_used");
selectvol.addEventListener("change", function() {
  var optionvol = selectvol.options[selectvol.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-volume");
  document.getElementById('medication_volume').value = optionvol;
  calcTotals();
  calcByweight();
});

function calcTotals(){
    $("#volume").text(req_dose * (med_vol / med_dose));
}
function calcByweight(){
    $("#perweight").text((req_dose * (med_vol / med_dose)) * weight);
}
</script>

Behaviour
The form populates and I added calctotals() after the populate to see if it would calculate the form however I keep getting either, NaN or Infinity.
The calculator will work again if I edit the form fields, but this defeats the point of the populate from the dropdown.

You need to update your variables so the calculator will take their actual expected value instead of the original 0. NaN as a result was yielded for you because your calculator divided by 0. I also added defaults to animal weight and required dose as well as the HTML:


//Add some options
let additionalOptions = [];
for (let myOption of [
    {
        $med_profile_id: 1,
        $mcd: 123,
        $mcv: 123,
        $med_common_name: "some name 1",
        $dose_type: 1,
        $volume_type: 1,
        $batch_number: 1,
        $exp: "something"
    },
    {
        $med_profile_id: 2,
        $mcd: 456,
        $mcv: 456,
        $med_common_name: "some name 2",
        $dose_type: 2,
        $volume_type: 2,
        $batch_number: 2,
        $exp: "something"
    },
]) {
    let {$med_profile_id, $mcd, $mcv, $med_common_name, $dose_type, $volume_type, $batch_number, $exp} = myOption;
    additionalOptions.push(
        `<option value="${$med_profile_id}" data-dose="${$mcd}" data-volume="${$mcv}">${$med_common_name} -${$mcd}<i>${$dose_type}</i>  in ${$mcv}<i>${$volume_type}</i> (${$batch_number} exp: ${$exp}) </option>`

    );
}
$("#stock_item_used").html($("#stock_item_used").html() + additionalOptions.join(""));
//Options added

var req_dose = 0;
var med_dose = 0;
var med_vol = 0;
var weight = 0;

$("#required_dose").change( function(){
    req_dose = $("#required_dose").val();
    calcTotals();
});
$("#medication_dose").change( function() {
    med_dose = $("#medication_dose").val();
    calcTotals();
});
$("#medication_volume").change( function() {
    med_vol = $("#medication_volume").val();
    calcTotals();
});
$("#animal_weight").change( function() {
    weight = $("#animal_weight").val();
    calcByweight();
});

var selectdose = document.getElementById("stock_item_used");
selectdose.addEventListener("change", function() {
  let context = selectdose.options[selectdose.selectedIndex]
  var optiondose = context.getAttribute("data-dose");
  document.getElementById('medication_dose').value = optiondose;
  var optionvol = context.getAttribute("data-volume");
  document.getElementById('medication_volume').value = optionvol;
  req_dose = context.getAttribute("data-dose");
  med_dose = $("#medication_dose").val();
  med_vol = $("#medication_volume").val();
  weight = $("#animal_weight").val();
  calcTotals();
  calcByweight();
});

function calcTotals(){
    $("#volume").text(req_dose * (med_vol / med_dose));
}
function calcByweight(){
    $("#perweight").text((req_dose * (med_vol / med_dose)) * weight);
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="stock_item_used" name="stock_item_used" id="stock_item_used" required>
        <option value="" disabled selected>Medication</option>
</select>
<input type="number" id="required_dose" placeholder="required dose" value="2">
<input type="number" id="medication_dose" placeholder="medication dose">
<input type="number" id="medication_volume" placeholder="medication volume">
<input type="number" id="animal_weight" placeholder="animal weight" value="10">
<div id="volume"></div>
<div id="perweight"></div>




That seems to have done the trick. Thank you.

@DanLindley happy to help
